# Link in Infobox using react-google-maps causes page reload

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I'm not able to put a react-router-dom Link inside of a react-google-maps InfoBox without causing a full page reload.

Here's the code for my InfoBox:

```js
import InfoBox from 'react-google-maps/lib/components/addons/InfoBox'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
class MyInfoBox extends Component {
  ...
  const options = {
    enableEventPropagation:false,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(loc.latitude, loc.longitude)
  };
  render(){
    return (
      <InfoBox options={options}>
        <Link to={`/location/${loc.id}`}>Go To Location</Link>
      </InfoBox>
    );
  }
}
```

All Links in my app work correctly, except for this one.

When the "Go To Location" link is clicked, a full-page reload is caused. I've tried to diagnose by following this issue: https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/issues/258, but I really don't know enough about the react router v4 to find out if the context contains the router object. Changing the value of `enableEventPropagation` does not change the behavior.

If anyone can help me understand why the Link is causing a page reload, I would really appreciate it.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try removing onClick prop in `<GoogleMap>` component and add `enableEventPropagation: true` to `<InfoBox>` options.

For me the issue was that `<GoogleMap>` onClick event was used to remove `<InfoBox>` when user clicks outside it. But turns out it is called also inside `<InfoBox>` so basically it was removing `<InfoBox>` with the `<Link>` inside it, before handling `<Link>` click.